# Pointer in function parameters c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, parameters, arguments

Consider this piece of code:

```
char strName[25]; 
void SetInfo(char *strName) 
{ 
strncpy(m_strName, strName, 25); 
}
```

Why are they using a pointer in the function parameter? Can't we just do this:

```
void SetInfo(char strName[]) {
strncpy(m_strName, strName, 25); }
```

? What is the difference between both?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, none at all (aside from one more letter to type). A char array "decays" to a pointer when passed to a function.

Answer (score -1):

**arrays always decay as pointers when passing as parameters.**

in this case array is like a pointer (they point to the memory of the first element of the array)

```cpp
void foo(char a[])
{
    a[0] = '@';
    cout << a[0];
    cout << *a;
}
```

Both calls to cout prints the same character '@'.

```cpp
void foo(char a[])
{
    // gives you the size of a pointer to the array's data type.
    // prints 4
    sizeof(a);

    // prints char *
    cout << typeid(a).name();
}
```

I'm not sure if this is standard.

Comment: Arrays aren't pointers. They decay when passed into a function by non-reference, among other things. The distinction is an important one.

Comment: @chris: Could you explain such cases? Thanks. (I said generally)

Comment: Well, for example, the decay does not happen if the array is passed into `sizeof`. The reason I said anything was because so many people have misconceptions that an array is a pointer, and that's completely wrong and just serves to confuse them when behaviour they expect from a pointer does not happen with an array.

Comment: @chris: it always does if it was received as the argument of a function. see the example above.